# Hidding a field if statement is true or false

Tags: asp-classic

I have two buttons on a page which i'd like one to show if the statement ireturn from a recordset is true else hide if false. for example if answer = boy the show button should show up else the don't show button should show.

```
<input type="submit"  name="button3" id="button3" value="Show" />

<input type="submit"  name="button3" id="button3" value="Don't Show" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Zam got it right. I would write it this way, though, because it is easier to modify:

```
<%
s_caption = "Do not Show"
if s_answer = "boy" then s_caption = "Show"
response.write ("<input type='submit'  name='button3' id='button3' value='" & s_caption & "' />")
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="submit"  name="button3" id="button3" value="<% If oRs("FieldName") = True Then Response.Write "Show" Else Response.Write "Do not show" End If %>" />
```